# Lang's preprint "Cyclotomic points, very anti-canonical varieties, and quasi-algebraic closure"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to find the following preprint of Serge Lang, which supposedly discusses his C1 conjecture:
"Cyclotomic points, very anti-canonical varieties, and quasi-algebraic closure".

I have not been able to find it on the web. Does anyone here have a scan or a copy which he or she is willing to share with me and MO?